# Json results add to html container

Tags: javascript, json, html, cordova

i have a Json result that i got through a webservice, now i want to see if it works, how do i make that Json values show in a button or link? and on page load?

one of the values returned looks like this : "name": "Muhammad Ali",
            "nickname": "The Greatest",

very new to json and javcascript.

Javascript and json :

```
    function Getdata() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "{}",
        url: "https://raw.github.com/appcelerator/Documentation-Examples/master/HTTPClient/data/json.txt",
        contentType: "application/json; cherset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        success: loadpage,
        failure: givealert
    });



    function loadpage(result) {
        if (resu.hasOwnProperty("d")) { result = res.d; }
        var data = JQuery.parseJSON(result);
    }

    function givealert(error) {
        alert('failed!!' + error);
    }
}
```

now how do i get it to show one value from the web-service in a label and on form load?
html markup for the label/button :

```
 <div id="listheight">
                <a type="button" id="routing" href="#datatapage"></a>
            </div>
```

i am using cordova/phonegap,Visual studi2010, html, javascript, css, jquerymobile and jquery1.8.2.

thanks in advance!

Comment: are u getting anything in ur var data ....i  mean var data = JQuery.parseJSON(result); .. if yes.. post wat u r json (returned value) (data in ur case)...

Comment: is there a way i can check that? cause windows phone sdk, dont support  debugging for javascript? thanks for ya quick reply :)\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use this HTML

```
<a type="button" id="routing" href="#datatapage" onclick="Getdata()">Click</a>
```

Use this code to call the method automatically on pageload

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // this is executed on page load
  Getdata();
});
```

and change your code to

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;

function Getdata() {
  var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "data/json.txt",  // better use a relative url here
    mimeType: "application/json; cherset=utf-8",
    success: loadpage,
    failure: givealert
  });

  function loadpage(result) {
    // this only displays you the values in a messagebox for you to check if it works
    // you can remove the following two lines
    alert("Name = "+result.fighters[0].name);
    alert("Nickname = "+result.fighters[0].nickname);
    // this changes the text
    document.getElementById("routing").innerHTML = result.fighters[0].name;
  }

  function givealert(error) {
    alert('failed!!' + error);
  }
}
```

I created a JSFiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/FUWyJ/
Note that the URL i send the request to is provided by JSFiddle and points to https://gist.github.com/4001105 where I made a copy of your sample data.

Comment: hey Lukas, thanks for quick reply i did what you said and still no response from application. and i even went on onclick? doesnt even hit the alert i put in after function getdata()?

Comment: edit on my comment -  it actually do hit the function, just not getting any data loaded into that button

Comment: Are you aware that your js file and the file you are POSTing to must be on the same domain? Otherwise, AJAX is not allowed to make a request to it. Do you access a file on the same site?

Comment: Ah, I see that you're using local files. Use the line `jQuery.support.cors = true;` in your js-file to allow remote requests from jQuery.

Comment: hey lukas, my url is down at the moment im gonna edit the url that i got from GitHub, and then i want the button to display only the 1st name on the page! and the nickname on another label! edited the question

Comment: this should work!,but it doesnt, no alert fires from loadpage(). i am very frustrated at this simple thing! but thanks alot for your time so long :)

Comment: hey Lukas, can you mayb try this on a jfiddle? i haveno idea how that works?

Comment: well that should work! but it doesnt :(, i put the window.getdata on a button click event , but it doesnt trigger anything? why would that be?...and sorry for the late post

Comment: Which browser are you using? It works with Firefox 16, the newest Opera and newest Safari.

Comment: on jsfiddle it works, but i am using a windows phone emulator, and there nothing pop's up as i click on it

Comment: nevermind! this works, was a webservice problem on my side! thanks for help :)